# Is there a way to store pipeline stages in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am about to create a simple model-pipeline using sklearn´s pipeline module:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

class TextTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None, *parg, **kwarg):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.key]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['text']], 
                                                        df['target'],
                                                        test_size=0.20) 
feature_pipeline =  Pipeline([
            ('transformer', TextTransformer(key='text')),
            ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1))),
            ('svd', TruncatedSVD(algorithm='randomized', n_components=150))
            ])

pickle.dump(feature_pipeline, open(../".pkl", 'wb'))
```

After initializing the feature selection, `feature_pipeline`, I´d like to call the created pipe on several models from other scripts, like (SVC as an example):

```
svc_pipeline = Pipeline([('features', feature_pipeline),
                      ('SVC',SVC())
                      ])
parameter_grid = {'SVC__kernel':['linear','rbf'],
                      'SVC__C':loguniform(1e-1, 1e2), 
                      'SVC__gamma':loguniform(1e-3, 1e0)}
svc_pipeline = RandomizedSearchCV(svc_pipeline, parameter_grid, n_iter = 10, cv=5,n_jobs = -1))

svc_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = svc_pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

So far, I´ve initialized each model in the same fashion and I´d assume the `feature_pipeline` has to be initialized for each model separately?!

As a workaround, I currently pickle the fitted `feature_pipeline`, transform and store the X_train, X_test matrices, like:

```
feature_pipeline.fit(X_train)
pickle.dump(feature_pipeline, open(../".pkl", 'wb'))

X_train_transformed = feature_pipeline.transform(X_train)
pickle.dump(X_train_transformed, open(../".pkl", 'wb'))

X_test_transformed = feature_pipeline.transform(X_test)
pickle.dump(X_test_transformed, open(../".pkl", 'wb'))
```

Is there a way to save the `feature_pipeline` directly so that it can be utilized without the need of applying this workaround? Or is there any other best practice?